# Send HTTP2 frame to server over TLS

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, http2

I am trying to learn how the HTTP2 protocol works. I see that Apple uses it for their push notification server. I am using the specification for the frame from [Discover HTTP](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#discover-http).

As a test, I wrote code that is supposed to communicate with that server. However, I keep getting the error that I'm missing the "Settings" frame.

My code is as follows:

```cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

#define SOCKET_ERROR -1

struct Frame  //Represents and HTTP2 Frame.
{
    char len[24];
    char type[8];
    char flags[8];
    char identifier[31];
    char payload[];
} __attribute__((packed));

void writeFrame(SSL* ssl)
{
    //First thing after connecting is to send the PREFACE.
    std::string preface = "PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\n";
    preface += "SM\r\n\r\n";

    SSL_write(ssl, preface.c_str(), preface.length());

    //Now to send the first frame. Aka the SETTINGS frame.
    Frame* frame = (Frame *)malloc(sizeof(Frame));
    memset(frame, 0, sizeof(Frame));

    int frameSize = 100;
    memcpy(frame->len, &frameSize, sizeof(frameSize));
    memcpy(frame->type, "SETTINGS", strlen("SETTINGS"));
    memcpy(frame->identifier, "SETTINGS", strlen("SETTINGS"));

    SSL_write(ssl, frame, sizeof(Frame));

    //Read server response.
    char buffer[10000];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int dataLen;
    while ((dataLen = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            std::cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    //The above gives me the error: 
    //First received frame was not SETTINGS. 
    //Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 6400000000

    //Try to POST to the server now.
    std::string payload = "POST /3/device HTTP/2.0\r\n";
    payload += ":method:POST\r\n";
    payload += ":scheme: https\r\n";
    payload += "cache-control: no-cache\r\n";
    payload += "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36\r\n";
    payload += "content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";

    int sentBytes = SSL_write(ssl, payload.c_str(), payload.length());

    if (sentBytes < payload.length() || sentBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return;
    }        

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    while ((dataLen = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            std::cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    std::string address = "api.development.push.apple.com";
    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    struct addrinfo* result = nullptr;

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(address.c_str(), nullptr, &hints, &result);

    int sock = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_addr = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(result->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = result->ai_family;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(443);
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (connect(sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_method());
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
    SSL_connect(ssl);

    writeFrame(ssl);

    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I send the `SETTINGS` frame and other frames to the server? What have I missed?

Comment: `PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\n` (et al) - Typically, there is ***one*** `CRLF` separating header options. The final option gets ***two*** `CRLF`. It looks like you wired two `CRLF` for every option. (And I could be wrong because I've never done what you are doing).

Comment: @jww, the preface of the OP is correct, as defined by [RFC 7540](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-3.5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors.

First of all, the `Frame` data structure, where the lengths of the array fields are wrong.
You seem to have copied their length in bits, but reported them in the `Frame` data structure in bytes.
You want this instead:

```c
struct Frame {
    char len[3];
    char type;
    char flags;
    char identifier[4];
    char payload[];
}
```

Furthermore, the type of the frame is not a string, nor is the identifier.

Finally, the format of the request is completely wrong, resembling HTTP/1.1, while the HTTP/2 format is completely different and based on HPACK.

I suggest you have a careful read of the [HTTP/2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540) before writing further code.

Comment: I used that structure (packed) to write the Settings frame with type = 0x4, flags = 0 and len = 0. Works but can't figure out how to write the "Headers" frame at all (type = 5, flags = 0x5, len = 020, identifier = 0001) then payload: `"Accept":"application/json"` but doesn't work.

Comment: @Brandon, HEADERS frame needs to be written using [HPACK](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-6.2).